# How can I automate the site setup process during installation?

Tags: 7, installation, distributions

I have this client requirement:

> While installing Drupal, user needs to do most of the configuration
>   himself.
>
> 1. Select the logo.
> 2. Select the theme.
> 3. Select the type of website he wants like blog, website, forum, eCommerce and when he does it, it should come along with its own configurations.

I know I need to use an installation profile. Is there any other way to do it? If an installation profile is the only way, then how can I meet all these requirements?

Comment: While my recommendation/answer leads to drush, I think drush and drush make use should be a separate question.

Comment: @Letharion - i have removed the drush error. Hi can i get you drupal folder after you have got the modules? Because i am unable to get it up and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you take a look at [NodeStream](https://drupal.org/project/nodestream) for examples. With a combination of install profile and [Features](https://drupal.org/project/features), you do a great deal of setup during the actual install. You could either build on top of that, which is what we do at work, or you could use it for examples.

Comment: I tried to install and its missing few modules like The following modules are required but were not found. Move them into the appropriate modules subdirectory, such as sites/all/modules. Missing modules: Uuid_node, Uuid_user, Uuid_role  i could not find these modules in drupal

Comment: What version are you using? I started a new project on the latest, alpha4, yesterday, and the build script worked fine.

Comment: I downloaded the latest today. I did not use drush. Is that the problem?

Comment: Well, NS just lists all of it's dependencies. You need to "drush make" for all of them to be downloaded. Or download them manually, but I wouldn't wanna do that.

Comment: yeah i was downloading manually. So i was not finding those modules.

Comment: How much time does it usually take to run 
drush make --no-core --contrib-destination=. nodestream.make
Its taking me more then 5 mins and its still not finished

Comment: I just tried it. Took me 3 minutes and 35 seconds.

Comment: Please see my question now. How do i resolve that error

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to install profiles, what might serve is if you manage the settings.php file with conf[] variables.